# Intel network adapter missing after kernel update to 18.04 kernel 4.15.0-1064-oem

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, kernel, ethernet, intel

The Intel network adapter is missing on my Precision 7920 and does not work after the kernel update.

- OS: Dell Ubuntu 18.04 preload image
- Kernel: 4.15.0-1064-oem

This is some more information:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1521] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell I350 Gigabit Network Connection [1028:1f9a]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 128 bytes
    Interrupt: pin D routed to IRQ 255
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at 92a00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Region 3: Memory at 92b04000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Expansion ROM at 92b80000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Masking: 00000000  Pending: 00000000
    Capabilities: [70] MSI-X: Enable- Count=10 Masked-
        Vector table: BAR=3 offset=00000000
        PBA: BAR=3 offset=00002000
    Capabilities: [a0] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 512 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset+ SlotPowerLimit 0.000W
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported+
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+ FLReset-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x4, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <4us, L1 <32us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x2, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+, LTR+, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 65ms to 210ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR+, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [e0] Vital Product Data
        Product Name: I350 GbE Controller  
        Read-only fields:
            [V0] Vendor specific: FFV18.0.11
            [PN] Part number: 6VDPG
            [MN] Manufacture ID: 31 30 32 38
            [V1] Vendor specific: DSV1028VPDR.VER2.0
            [V3] Vendor specific: DTINIC
            [V4] Vendor specific: DCM3001FFFFFF4101FFFFFF
            [V5] Vendor specific: NPY2
            [V6] Vendor specific: PMT13
            [V7] Vendor specific: NMVIntel Corp
            [RV] Reserved: checksum good, 2 byte(s) reserved
        Read/write fields:
            [Y1] System specific: CCF0
        End
    Capabilities: [100 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt+ RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP+ FCP+ CmpltTO+ CmpltAbrt+ UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC+ UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr+ BadTLP+ BadDLLP+ Rollover+ Timeout+ NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn+ ChkCap+ ChkEn+
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Device Serial Number f8-bc-12-ff-ff-ff-ff-03
    Capabilities: [150 v1] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
        ARICap: MFVC- ACS-, Next Function: 1
        ARICtl: MFVC- ACS-, Function Group: 0
    Capabilities: [1a0 v1] Transaction Processing Hints
        Device specific mode supported
        Steering table in TPH capability structure
    Capabilities: [1c0 v1] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Max snoop latency: 71680ns
        Max no snoop latency: 71680ns
    Capabilities: [1d0 v1] Access Control Services
        ACSCap: SrcValid- TransBlk- ReqRedir- CmpltRedir- UpstreamFwd- EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
        ACSCtl: SrcValid- TransBlk- ReqRedir- CmpltRedir- UpstreamFwd- EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
    Kernel modules: igb

01:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1521] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell I350 Gigabit Network Connection [1028:1f9a]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 128 bytes
    Interrupt: pin C routed to IRQ 255
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at 92900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Region 3: Memory at 92b00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Expansion ROM at <ignored> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Masking: 00000000  Pending: 00000000
    Capabilities: [70] MSI-X: Enable- Count=10 Masked-
        Vector table: BAR=3 offset=00000000
        PBA: BAR=3 offset=00002000
    Capabilities: [a0] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 512 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset+ SlotPowerLimit 0.000W
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported+
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+ FLReset-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x4, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <4us, L1 <32us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x2, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+, LTR+, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 65ms to 210ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [e0] Vital Product Data
        Product Name: I350 GbE Controller  
        Read-only fields:
            [V0] Vendor specific: FFV18.0.11
            [PN] Part number: 6VDPG
            [MN] Manufacture ID: 31 30 32 38
            [V1] Vendor specific: DSV1028VPDR.VER2.0
            [V3] Vendor specific: DTINIC
            [V4] Vendor specific: DCM3001FFFFFF4101FFFFFF
            [V5] Vendor specific: NPY2
            [V6] Vendor specific: PMT13
            [V7] Vendor specific: NMVIntel Corp
            [RV] Reserved: checksum good, 2 byte(s) reserved
        Read/write fields:
            [Y1] System specific: CCF0
        End
    Capabilities: [100 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt+ RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP+ FCP+ CmpltTO+ CmpltAbrt+ UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC+ UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr+ BadTLP+ BadDLLP+ Rollover+ Timeout+ NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn+ ChkCap+ ChkEn+
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Device Serial Number f8-bc-12-ff-ff-ff-ff-03
    Capabilities: [150 v1] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
        ARICap: MFVC- ACS-, Next Function: 0
        ARICtl: MFVC- ACS-, Function Group: 0
    Capabilities: [1a0 v1] Transaction Processing Hints
        Device specific mode supported
        Steering table in TPH capability structure
    Capabilities: [1d0 v1] Access Control Services
        ACSCap: SrcValid- TransBlk- ReqRedir- CmpltRedir- UpstreamFwd- EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
        ACSCtl: SrcValid- TransBlk- ReqRedir- CmpltRedir- UpstreamFwd- EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
    Kernel modules: igb
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that there is error in `dkms` log.

Remove `dkms` by following command could fix the issue:

```
sudo apt-get purge oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22-dkms.deb"

DKMS make.log for oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22-0.2 for kernel 4.15.0-1064-oem (x86_64)
Wed Nov 27 02:27:57 EST 2019
make: Entering directory '/var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build'
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-1027-oem'
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-1064-oem'
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-1027-oem/Makefile:975: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/igb_main.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/e1000_api.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/igb_ethtool.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/igb_hwmon.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/e1000_mbx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/e1000_mac.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/e1000_manage.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/e1000_nvm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/igb_param.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/e1000_phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/igb_procfs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/igb_vmdq.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/e1000_82575.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/e1000_i210.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/igb_debugfs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/igb_ptp.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/kcompat.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/igb.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/igb.mod.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build/igb.ko
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-1064-oem'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-1027-oem'
make: Leaving directory '/var/lib/dkms/oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22/0.2/build'
```